# PHP OOP Performance : Parameter or Instance Variable?

Tags: php, performance, oop, parameters, instance-variables

Im curious about getting an answer for a OOP question but can't find any info so far.

Here goes, writing classes and methods is it faster to pass in parameters for each method or use instance/field variables and $this->x;

Which would be faster at run time?

```
class ExampleByParameter(){

 function SomeMethod($a,$b){
 echo $a." ".$b;
 return;
 }

}
```

or

```
class ExampleByInstance(){

 function __construct($a,$b){
 $this->a=$a;
 $this->b=$b;
 }

 function SomeMehtod(){
 $a=$this->a;
 $b=$this->b;
 echo $a." ".$b;
 return;
 }

}
```

I would imagine their would be no difference with the examples above but im thinking there might be a significant difference with more complicated code.

Comment: This would be a micro optimization at best. Don't focus on it.

Comment: Think of usability : what if you need $a and $b in another functions ? you'll pass it in parameters each time ? It's procedural and not OOP anymore

Comment: ExampleByInstance might be faster compared to ExampleByParameter.

Comment: **Code what you mean first!** Performance is not the deciding factor here, it's a matter of class design and what your code is supposed to do. The performance difference will be minimal if it exists at all, you will ***not*** see an overall 300% speedup or anything like it. Worry about performance when your program is proven to be too slow!

Comment: This kind of decision must be made by considering the public interface of the class, not performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The performance differece is going to be negligible. You should really be deciding which pattern is best for your class structure.

Does your class depend on `$a` and `$b` to operate properly? Put them in the constructor.

Is `SomeMethod` public? Does it do anything with the supplied variables beyond what it returns? If so, keep them as parameters.

In a large-scale project, you will gain more benefit from accurate class design vs negligible performance improvements.

Comment: Thanks for the info i was wondering if there was a clear winner, however it seems that there is alot more to think about when designing your classes.