# Passing parameter by method or class?

Tags: php, oop, parameter-passing

I have a class which is containing multiple methods. So I want to know which approach in better?

**Passing by methods:**

```
class cls {

    function method1($var){
        echo $var;
    }

    function method2($var){
        echo $var;
    }

}

$obj = new cls;
$obj->methodX($var); // X can be 1,2
```

**Passing by class:**

```
class cls {

    public $var;
    function __construct($var){
        $this->var = $var;
    }

    function method1(){
        echo $this->var;
    }

    function method2(){
        echo $this->var;
    }

}

$obj = new cls($var);
$obj->methodX(); // X can be 1,2
```

**Note:** I need to `$var` in all methods. Also in reality there is almost 10 methods.

Comment: There is no general answer to this. It depends on what `$var` is meant to express in relation to the class. If it is a value that somehow describes the object or is a property of the object or its behavior then it should be modeled as such. If it is unrelated to the class or object, but just a runtime parameter or an output addition, then it should be provided at runtime, where required.

Comment: @arkascha I see, thanks.

Comment: You should explain your real business case rather than trying to get an answer from an artificial problem.

Answer (score 0):

From a design point I would go for passing it with the class. It allows you to only pass your parameter once. It also removes the dependency that you have on your argument in each method/function in which you want to call a method.

The performance comparison between both is neglectable ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007658/php-oop-performance-parameter-or-instance-variable)).

Comment: It doesn't remove the dependency, it just hides it from the method and couples it to the class. Depending on the context this does not have to be a bad thing but since we don't know the context, such a general answer is dangerous advice.